# Android Instant App without having a verified website

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

To build an Instant App it is required to setup App Links. One of the steps  requires to verify that you are the owner of the website you are linking your app to.
Is it possible to create an Instant App if I don't have any website but still want to have ability to send a link to my Instant App to a friend, share in on social media etc?

Basically the idea is to implement "share" feature in the app that will generate a link that will be leading to the instant app.

Comment: Please also read these to understand how Instant Apps requires App Links:
https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#app-links
and 
https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html#app_links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instant Apps requires a link to a domain via App Links as Instant Apps are triggered/launched via a URL. There would be no way to launch an Instant App without connecting it to a domain. It's not necessarily required to host an actual website at that domain (aside from hosting the `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file) although it is recommended (so that if a non-Instant App enabled device reaches that URL it actually shows something meaningful).

There's nothing to stop you registering and using some arbitrary domain and verifying it via App Links for the functionality you describe. You can use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) to very quickly set up hosting for free and add your `assetlinks.json` file (and of course there a multitude of other options to host that file as well).